# What's the name and where can I find this strange RTL character?

Tags: unicode, special-characters, right-to-left

See, I've just found out something that impressed and confused me at the same time. There's this strange character which allows you to type everything reversed by default. For example, if I type:

```
"Something like this"
```

Then it will turn out into:

```
‮"Something like this"
```

(being that I didn't have to reverse the sentence myself, if you get what I mean).

It looks like I'm trolling you, but I'm not. To make sure you get what I'm trying to say, I'll paste the special character right below in a separate (code) line.

```
‮
```

Now try to copy it, paste somewhere else in a text box and start typing. You'll see something **very strange** happening.

The question is: what's the name of this crazy invisible character which forces everything to be typed in right-to-left language?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to mean.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to a [Right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)?

Comment: Nope, @MJH. I checked this both on the Charmap and other page (http://superuser.com/questions/769024/is-there-any-way-to-reverse-text-and-character-direction-in-a-pure-text-docume), nothing suited my answer. Can't find it somewhere else.

Comment: [how is this valid Java code? (obfuscated Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36824416/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the "['RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE' (U+202E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm)" character.

Here's some discussion about it (and possible security concerns) over on StackOverflow:

- [Unicode mirror character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115204/unicode-mirror-character)

Comment: Alright! You got it! Thanks for the help! =)